# JBoss - Spring Web Project - Need to have jsessionid in URL to remain sticky in JBoss Cluster solution

Tags: java, spring, jboss, web, jsessionid

I currently have a web project that is built on Spring and JBoss 7.1.1. We have implemented a solution with clustering and high availability. I dont know too much about this side of things.

What I have been told though, is I need to have the jsessionid within the URL to ensure that it remains sticky to one node in the cluster.

In my Spring securirty configuration, I had previoulsy added the following, as when I accessed the bookmarked URL it appended the jsessionid to the URL:

```
<http auto-config="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
```

Removing this alone, does not make it sticky to the one node.

Can anyone tell me know to do this?

Comment: What kind of load balancer are you using? Are you using mod-cluster or external load balancer like apache?

Comment: If you using mod_cluster here is a link that might be useful to you - https://community.jboss.org/thread/170895.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting following configuration in `web.xml?

```
<session-config>
    <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

works with Servlet 3.0+ as far as i know.

keep in mind, that you still need the `disable-url-rewriting="false"` configuration.